# change method doesn't invoke callback when I change input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

I wrote following javascript code:

```
 $("#email").change(function () {
        email = $("#email").val()
        if (validateEmail(email)) {
            $('#button').enable();
        } else {
            $('#button').disable();
        }
    })
```

Also I have following form:

```
<form name='register_form' action="<c:url value='/register_new_user' />" method='POST'
            onsubmit="return validateRegisterForm(this);">

            <div class="input-line">
            <input type="text" class="text" name='email' id='email' />


            <div class="input-line bottom">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="зарегистрироваться" id='button' />
            </div>

</form>
```

function passed to change method doesn't execute when I change value of input.

Why? how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the event fire on "blur" of the input field? I don't think it naturally fires on keypress.

If you wanted it on keypress, you could just use `.bind('input', function(){...`

Answer (score 0):

The browser is showing any error for you? Like missing components or not finding elements? It can gives a clue about what is happening